# How to adjust the height of a View that is contained in a row of TableLayout

Tags: java, android, view, tablelayout, tablerow

This what i get in my `Activity`:

http://img855.imageshack.us/img855/2056/androidscreenshot.jpg

The activity is filled by a `TableLayout`. The `TableLayout` in turn is filled by 2 `TableRow` that are Two `View` containing a 100x100 cyan bitmap. The yellow area is the background of the activity in position (1,1) of the TableView. The red area is the background of the activity in position (1,2).

The problem is that i cannot see the other two cyan bitmap in position (2,1) and (2,2). I think the problem is that the View in the first row are resized in the width but not in the height. So the view in the first row obscure the view in the second row.

If i add to the `View` both `ViewGroup.LayoutParams` or `LayoutParams` with `WRAP_CONTENT` i get a `java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero`

This is my code:

```
public class HIDActivity extends Activity
{

    boolean toggle = false;            
    TableLayout IFaceLayout;
    TableRow TButtons1;
    TableRow TButtons2;
    TableRow TArea;
    SimpleButton TButton1;
    SimpleButton TButton2;
    SimpleButton TButton3;
    SimpleButton TButton4;


    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
    {
        super.onCreate(icicle);


        TButton1 = new SimpleButton(this);
        TButton2 = new SimpleButton(this);
        TButton3 = new SimpleButton(this);
        TButton4 = new SimpleButton(this);

        TButtons1 = new TableRow(this);
        TButtons2= new TableRow(this);

        TButtons1.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT , LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT ) );
        TButtons2.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT , LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT ) );

        TButtons1.addView(TButton1);                
        TButtons1.addView(TButton2);
        TButtons2.addView(TButton3);
        TButtons2.addView(TButton4);

        IFaceLayout = new TableLayout(this);
        IFaceLayout.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT , LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT ) );
        IFaceLayout.setStretchAllColumns(true);

        IFaceLayout.addView(TButtons1);
        IFaceLayout.addView(TButtons2);

        setContentView(IFaceLayout);
        IFaceLayout.requestLayout();
    }


    class SimpleButton extends View
    {
        BitmapDrawable ButtonImage;
        Paint Style;
        int i , j ;
        int width , heigth;

        public SimpleButton(Context context) 
        {
            super(context);
            Style = new Paint();

            if(toggle == false) 
            {    
                this.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                toggle = true;
            }    
            else 
            {    
                this.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                toggle = false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
        {       
            ButtonImage = new BitmapDrawable(Bitmap.createBitmap(100 , 100 , Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)); 
            this.width = ButtonImage.getBitmap().getWidth();
            this.heigth = ButtonImage.getBitmap().getHeight();

            for(i = 0 ; i < width ; i++)
            {                
                for(j = 0 ; j < heigth ; j++)
                {
                    ButtonImage.getBitmap().setPixel(i, j, Color.CYAN);
                }
            }

            canvas.drawBitmap(ButtonImage.getBitmap() , 0 , 0 , Style);        
        }        
    }
}
```

Could someone please help me with this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hint of **Gophermofur** i partially correct.

It's correct to call MyView.setLayoutParams and passing it the Layout object that match the type of the object in which MyView is contained. However in order to permit the container to control the size of the contained object i have to use MATCH_PARENT instead of WRAP_CONTENT.

In addition i have partially resolved setting manually the height to 100. That is:

```
TButton1.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT , 100);
```

Now i get the 4 square:

http://img152.imageshack.us/img152/1530/androidscreenshot3.jpg

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be that the SimpleButton that extends a View is not being set to wrap_content vertically.

When setting the layout paramters, you want to use the container where the object will be residing. When you define your layout paramters, you are really saying "This is how my object/view is going to fill the space of the container it is housed within". In this case, your button will be sitting inside a table row, so you should define the layout parameters relative to the table row, like this:

```
TButton1.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT , LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT ) );

TButton2.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT , LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT ) );

TButton3. [same thing]
TButton4. [same thing]
```

You may need to change your TButtons layout paramters as well to be relative to a TableLayout, since a TableRow is housed within a table layout.

```
TButtons1.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT , LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT ) );            
TButtons2.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT , LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT ) );
```

Your table layout is also housed within a parent layout. I'm not sure what it is, but it would be the root of your xml file (probably), which is most likely a Relative or Linear layout. You should define the Table layout parameters according to whatever parent layout it sits in.

```
IFaceLayout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT , LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT ) );
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately doing so i get this:
[link](http://img716.imageshack.us/img716/9800/androidscreenshot2.jpg)
I tried to change WRAP_CONTENT with MATCH_PARENT but the result was the previous:
[link](http://img855.imageshack.us/img855/2056/androidscreenshot.jpg)